# Solaris OS version and Bit

Tags: operating-systems, solaris

What does mean below output from Solaris , How to find out the version and bit of OS from this output?

```
uname -a
SunOS tsap01 5.10 Generic_147441-27 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SunOS 5.7 and later, drop the "5." to get the Solaris version number, so "5.10" is Solaris 10.  To see which update release of Solaris 10, you need to look in `/etc/release`.

To see if it's running 32-bit or 64-bit you need to run `isainfo -kv` as uname won't tell you.

Answer (score 0):

The version is SunOS 5.10
and its 32 bit (i386)

Comment: You can't tell from uname on Solaris if it's 32-bit or 64-bit - both report "i386" from uname to maintain compatibility with the 32-bit releases.  You need to use "isainfo -k" to see which kernel is booted (both 32-bit & 64-bit are installed on Solaris 10 x86, so you can boot either one from the same install).